# How to send email in background in Android?

Tags: android, email

For my app, I have retrieved my message `inbox/sent`. Now I want to send that retrieved data on my email address.how can it be? Is any authentication required for it? Also I have tried to download the authentication files (authentication.jar,mail.jar) but can't succeeded.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long pastThreeHour = currentTime - (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 3);
    String[] selectionArgs = { "" + pastThreeHour, "" + currentTime };

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, "date DESC");

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")); // check for null
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")); // convert to date its long
            String message_text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")); // check type and get names

            // send email from here
            sendSMSEmail(number, date, message_text, type);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to send email in background use following code, to send email

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
{   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   
    private Multipart _multipart;

    static 
    {   
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) 
    {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
    {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception 
    {   
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   

        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        message.setContent(_multipart);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   

    }   

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception 
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource 
    {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) 
        {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) 
        {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) 
        {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() 
        {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException 
        {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() 
        {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException 
        {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

and

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() 
    {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() 
        {
            public Void run() 
            {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You would be requiring [activation.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar), [additionnal.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar) & [mail.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar) files

Comment: Can u please point out that where should I put the data in this code which I have to send through mail ?

Comment: @BarunKumar , which data ?

Comment: ....the data which I have to send through mail.

Comment: do you mean file or the email details ?

Comment: Actually I am retrieving some data in another class and want to send that data through email.I can't understand how to pass my retrieved data in this GMailSender class.these data is in String Format

Comment: can you upload your code in question ?

Comment: sendSMSEmail(number, date, message_text, type);this is the retrieved data which is to pass in this above class

Comment: Are you getting values in your String variables ?

Comment: yes, in <sendSMSEmail(number, date, message_text, type);>.I want to retrieve data here. and now want to pass this  in GmailSender class to send mail

Comment: If you are getting the values then it should pass automatically. What values in email you are getting ?

Comment: Please give ur email id.I will send u my code and discuss all about

Comment: through the 1st code 
I want to retrieve data (Inbox/sent message) and through 2nd and 3rd code send it to my email Address.

Comment: I will get back to you on this, at present I am on a task.

Comment: [Download the JAR files](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads)

Answer (score 6):

There is a library for Sending Email in Background which is working efficient.
You can get the library from here [Background Mail Library](https://github.com/nlubello/BackgroundMailLibrary)

Now import this library in your eclipse, and then go to project properties and add this library to your project.
After all this process, just put these code in your project, and it will send email in background.

```
BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(context);
bm.setGmailUserName("sendername@gmail.com");
bm.setGmailPassword("sender_email_password");
bm.setMailTo("receiver@gmail.com");
bm.setFormSubject("Subject");
bm.setFormBody("Body");
bm.send();
```

With this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Update 1: Updated the Library name

Comment: It is giving  "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException". I had also enabled the allow access to less secured apps....any solution?

Comment: @Chetu did you enter the valid email id and password and receiver id,it may seem problem in your mail credential

Comment: Link is dead, please update the link: https://github.com/nlubello/BackgroundMailLibrary

Comment: @S.R Thank you for the suggestion. I have been updated

Comment: Is this still stable? I noticed the most recent update was several years ago.

Comment: how to compile this library? cant figure out

Comment: THIS IS ECLIPSE BASED LIBRARY BRO

Comment: Before to try sending mail, you may need to 'allow less secure apps' for your sender mail address. For more info : https://docs.mailshake.com/article/38-blocked-sign-in-attempt-and-less-secure-app-notification