# Send forget password email

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have spent lot of time, but alas! I am stuck in this problem. I want to send email in background in android application but I can't find way, how can I do it. Please anybody tell me some way how can I send background email in android application for forget password.

Comment: what do you mean by background email. provide more details on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to send email when user forget their password in android application.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947685/how-to-send-email-in-background-in-android

Comment: Also, you could look into using something existing for this. E.g. http://docs.apigee.com/api-baas/content/resetting-user-password-3

Comment: Yes, I have read this site and use "BackgroundMail Library" but, it is not accepting my code just showing red lines in code at BackgroundMail and other words.

Comment: For something like this where the user is going to be able to reset the password, you don't want that to originate on the device itself or pass through it.  If I reset your password, that email shouldn't be flowing through my device or my network.

Answer (score 2):

I use a backend like [Backendless](https://backendless.com/) that allow you to manage your users login, password recovery, register, etc..

Good API, easy to use and a great and growing community who can help you any time.

Comment: At this time I am using Parse for login, signup and forget password.

Comment: If you are using Parse, just add a Button in your UI. When you touch this button (on the OnClickActionListener) add the Parse forget password method..

Comment: yes, I have add a button and you just tell me about "Parse forget password method".